# How to close current tab after submit form in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have create list in SharePoint 2013 now i want close tab after submission form or need help on redirect page after submission or cancel button. I have read lot of website like [Here](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/06/sharepoint-redirecting-to-page-after.html)

But i cant understand kindly give solution.

Below is screenshot for your reference.

[image: This my thanks page]

[image: Coding Part]

Answer (score 0):

1 way is to copy and paste the new form in SharePoint designer, then customize the save and cancel button, let me know if it is unclear

```
 <input type="button" class="contact-button" value="Submit and Create New Request" name="btnSaven" onclick="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$ctl47$g_e2e6263d_1b99_4ec6_8e13_9683d5761887','__commit;__redirect={}')">
```

in redirect you can type your redirect link

Comment: sorry, where to place this tag? and i dont know how to place this code.

Comment: copy the newForm.aspx and paste it, this will create a  new custom newForm.aspx in sharepoint designer, edit that file and find for 'save' button and change it there. edit this __redirect={"url"}

Comment: I have create thanks.aspx from NewForm.aspx but in that thanks.aspx only ASP.NET coding so i cant find input tag. I have found " <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
" like this.

Comment: remove the content there and add like below :<table>
          <tr>
      <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
      <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
       <input type="button" class="contact-button" value="Submit and Create New Request" name="btnSaven" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={}')}" /> let me know if is unclear

Comment: : I have made correction but after submission page not redirect and i have attached screenshot FYI

Comment: sorry but i am not able to locate screen shot , where you have added?

Comment: Kindly check my screenshot now.

Comment: just check once the syntax how to refer url in redirect, i will check it once i have some time sorry..

Comment: i checked it is working for me please try again this :

Comment: <input type="button" class="contact-button" value="Submit and Create New Request" name="btnSaven" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://www.google.co.in}')}"/>

Comment: Your coding adding additional button in my form i want redirect when already exists Save and Cancel and also i have create submit button in Info path.